# How can I move the Related Products to specific location on view page

Tags: blocks, product-view

I'm having trouble moving the related products block to a specific area on my view page.

I'd like to move the block right above the easy-tabs but when I try to specify either *above=Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Additional* it appears as the header  and if I use * bellow=Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Media" * it appears bellow the easytabs extension.

Here is a snippet of my **catalog.xml**:

```
            <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" befo="Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Additional" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
    </reference>
  <reference name="right">
        <!--<block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>-->
    </reference> 
</catalog_product_view>
```

**Desired Result**

[image]

How can I move the related products block above the easy tabs extension (or Product_View_Additional block)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First set **System -> configuration -> easy tabs -> Enable related products** tab to No. So now remove related product tabs.

Then create a local.xml file inside layout directory of your active theme. then add following code.

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.additional">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view></layout>
```

If already exist local.xml, then add following code

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info.additional">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_related" name="catalog.product.related" before="-" template="catalog/product/list/related.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Clear magento cache.

Comment: Okay I got this to work, but is it best practice?

Comment: I updated the code. This is the best practice of magento layout.

Comment: Beautiful! This method is cleaner and if I ever remove the easytabs I won't loose the modification, thanks! +1